# What kind of Django Model inheritance should i use for multiple classes storing different information of a single person?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am new to coding and Django, I need to have 5 model classes to store different info about a person (basic info, medical history,diet,exercise). The fields need not be related to each other across the tables but i want to have the cascade delete option(ie basic info fields like age etc are not related to medical conditions or exercise, but they all are information for a single person).

I tried the making the basic info a parent class and used Multitable inheritance, but it gave me duplicate entries of all the parent class fields in the database.
I tried making an abstract class and rest all classes as child classes, but in this case i dint have the cascade delete option(i.e if i delete a persons basic info, his medical history still remains in db).
How do i approach this?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you require inheritance specifically? Won't it be useful to just create relationship between the user table and other info tables. I would recommend you to create normalized relations and implement those relations in your Django models. Do please be sure of your database structure before directly jumping into coding.

Comment: I am new to coding, so not sure how things work. What do you mean by normalized relations? i tried using the concept of foreign key too, but it messed up my forms as the fields are not really related to each other, but the tables need to be. @Sanip , Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think it would be a lot more clearer if you could show what you have achieved until now. So can you post your models and forms?